# VBA Excel adding a dynamic validation list

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a worksheet in which I am trying to programmatically add DataValidation-Lists when appropriate to the `Range(BF:BZ)`

Currently all cells in `Range(D3:D500)` use a DataValidation list `=type` and I have a `sub` that checks if any cells in that range change. If so it updates all the cells in that row. When I get to the **options** range it references a table on a separate sheet for what to fill in.

[image: example of different types]

At this point when filling each **option** I need to also create a DataValidation-list when appropriate, based on the text in the cell. row 6 is an example of results that would require a list, while rows 3 through 5 have multiple results that should just be left as is (for someone to manually type in an ID later or something along those lines)

```
Dim formString As String
Let formString = "=" & Range(colAddress)
Range(colAddress).Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=formString
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "InputTitle"
    .ErrorTitle = "ErrorTitle"
    .InputMessage = "InputMsg"
    .ErrorMessage = "ErrorMsg"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

This code works in the case that there is a valid DataValidation-list, but I get a `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` when `formString` has values such as `speed_OW`

Would I have to make essentially a list of lists which contains all the valid lookups and call something like `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Range(colAddress),listOfLists,1,FALSE),"No List")`

Or is there a cleaner way of doing this so as to:  if a data-validation-list exists for the current cell then set it, else leave the cell alone for the user to manually change

**Edit for additional information below**

So in another question someone mentioned making references to the *Name Manager* and I think just looking through that is all I need to check in a conditional. I will try this tomorrow

Comment: You can try removing `Let` and leaving just the remaining part in that row: `formString = "=" & Range(colAddress)`

Comment: It seems to function the same way even after removing `Let`. Existing validation-lists populate fine, but it still throws `Run-time error '1004'` if the list does not exist

Comment: You need some sort of error handling. Something like `on error goto: errorhandler` and then add  `errorhandler: some commands here` to the end of the sub.

Comment: Is there a syntax that I can effectively wrap the entire `With Selection.Validation ... End With` in an `IFERROR()` as that block of code is in a loop that checks each Option column in the row that was changed (of which, there are 20 options) and I need to just leave the cell unmodified only if there was no **Name (see edit for details**